# Как в BASH в переменную занести все содержимое текстового файла?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Как в BASH в переменную занести все содержимое текстового файл что бы потом можно было работать с этой переменной через substring?

К примеру у меня есть файл text.txt в нем есть строки:

```
<hr>
Hello im text now
Im text, you know it
Or not?
I am Text
Hi, how are you Text. How do you feel?
```

и так далее... мне нужно, если в строке есть слово "text" узнать какой по счету этот символ, и от него выделить определенное количество символов и записываю это в другой файл.

Comment: самый простой способ `VAR=$(cat text.txt)`

Comment: Большое спасибо)

Comment: @кими Это задание из какого то курса или по работе? Вам Баракин дал наводку, что лучше оболочкой (bash в вашем случае) это не делать есть много верных инструментов для этого.

Answer (score 2):

> Мне нужно нужно, если в строке есть слово "text" узнать какой по счету этот символ, и от него выделить определенное количество символов и записываю это в другой файл.

т.е., фактически, вам надо получить несколько символов из строк, стоящих после `text`.

средствами оболочки (хоть программы *bash*, хоть любой другой) это сделать, конечно, можно, но получится довольно громоздко.

лучше воспользоваться программами, более подходящими для манипуляций с текстом.

например, программой *sed*:

```
$ sed -rn 's/.*text(.{4}).*/\1/p' файл
```

для вашего примера команда выведет по 4 символа (стоящие после `text`) из каждой строки, где встречается `text`:

```
 now
, yo
```

сохранить *stdout* программы в другой файл:

```
$ программа опции и аргументы > другой.файл
```

Answer (score 1):

VVV=`cat ...`  
Только вам нужно не это. Тут нужно построчное чтение в цикле.

Comment: Если не трудно, буду очень признателен Вашей помощи. Можите на примере написать как этого достичь через цыкл. Я в Баше новичек, и пока что многое не понимаю..

Comment: Строку читает команда read. Дальше пока не дочитал. Я тоже не бог весть какой спец в bash ;)

Answer (score 1):

Вопросу скоро год, но все же.

в цикле по количеству слов по строке, ищем совпадение заданного совпадения текста при помощи awk команда:

```
echo -e "Hello im text now\nIm text, you know it\nOr not?\nI am Text\nHi, how are you Text. How do you feel?" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /([T|t][E|e][X|x][T|t])([^A-z])?/ ) print i,$i,NR,$(i+1); }'
```

результат можно регулировать или меня

`print i,$i,NR,$(i+1)`

`i - номер искомого значения в строке`

`$i - печать искомого значения в строке`

`NR - номер строки где найдено совпадение`

`$(i+1) - печатаем слово +1 от найденного совпадения, в минус не будет работать`

ну и соответсвенно для вывода в файл дописать в конце `> /text2.txt`

Для проверки работоспособности переходим
https://rextester.com/live/ESTT82921

upd: Не нужно записывать в переменную файл для работы, итоговая команда будет выглядеть так если перейти в каталог с text.txt:

```
cat ./text.txt | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ( $i ~ /([T|t][E|e][X|x][T|t])([^A-z])?/ ) print i,$i,NR,$(i+1); }' > ./text2.txt
```